# Should I add my own answer?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering about adding my own answer to:

[How to fix a seized V-Brake arm?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/44574/how-to-fix-a-seized-v-brake-arm)

Chris H's answer pretty much nailed it, but some of the comments were helpful as well and I thought it might be useful to collect all the points together. On the other hand experienced members of the site are probably thinking this was such a straightforward question as to be hardly worth the fuss.

So my question is should I add my own answer as a summary of the advice received and how the repair went?

Comment: The other option is to add the extra stuff to Chris H's answer.

Comment: @andy256 - maybe as comments. But I'm not sure that editing ChrisH's answer if there are other things is the right thing to do, since it can change meaning.

Comment: @Batman I'm thinking more of adding the useful bits as a clear addition from the OP, but retaining the answer as the accepted one. Chris hasn't chimed in; it'd be good to get his view.

Answer (score 7):

Totally, yes, 100% go for it.

Remember SE is all about the Question and its Answers, and part of that is getting the best possible set of answers.

You can even accept your own answer, because its the solution that worked for you.  Or you can leave ChrisH with the accepted answer because that was the most helpful.  Either is fine.

Closure is incredibly helpful for people searching later.....

[image: From https://xkcd.com/979/]

From https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: ...worse is searching, finding an answer that describes your problem exactly, sounds really familiar, and maybe uses hostnames like yours.  Then you realise its a posting from 10 years beforehand, from yourself.

Comment: No, trust me, someone else asking the exact question, a pile of random broken links, then a reply at the end "that fixed it, thanks". That is the absolute worst.

Comment: I think the right thing to do would be to accept ChrisH's answer and write your own (or comments to the answer) to summarize what you did in addition to it, since OP said ChrisH's answer was essentially correct.